# Simple regex stumping me: Find everything but specific pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I've been scouring the internet and on regexpal for about an hour and half now trying to get a very simple piece of regex working. I have a script that iterates over more than 100 strings that all start with: `5_<1-109>_<text>` and I want to match everything after the second `_` so I've created the very straightforward regex:

`5_[0-9]*_`

The only problem I'm having is inverting it. I've tried lookaheads but I think I'm messing up the syntax somehow and I'm at wits end.

Thanks

---

Edit: Here are a few example strings, as requested:

```
5_100_foo_bar
5_01_string_name
5_99_blah_blah
5_109_hip_hip
5_16_hooray
5_05_they_can_be_any_length_and_most_but_not_all_have_underscores
```

---

Edit2: Thanks for all the replies, they all look like they work, I wish I could choose multiple answers :(

---

For those interested, here is the complete script that resulted from this post:

```
#!/bin/bash
     for fl in *.tcl; do

     #Remove extention
     replace=${fl:0:${#fl}-4}

     #Remove prefix
     find=$(sed -r 's/5_[0-9]+_(.*)/\1/' <<< $replace)

     echo Filename: $fl
     echo REPLACESTRING: $replace
     echo FINDSTRING: $find

     sed -i s/$find/$replace/g $fl
     done
```

It goes through all my .tcl files, strips the extention and saves that value, then strips the topic prefix off of that one and finally does a find/replace in the file with these two values. Hopefully someone in the future will see this and be able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex of the form

```
[^_]+$
```

[**Rgex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aD4dX5/1)

**Test**

```
$ echo 5_100_abc | sed -r 's/[^_]+$/xxx/'
5_100_xxx

$ echo 5_2_abc | sed -r 's/[^_]+$//'
5_2_
```

**Edit**

```
$ sed -r 's/5_[0-9]+_(.*)/\1/' inputFile
foo_bar
string_name
blah_blah
hip_hip
hooray
they_can_be_any_length_and_most_but_not_all_have_underscores
```

Comment: The strings after the first bit usually contain underscores as well. I didn't include enough information, I apologize. I've updated my post with a few examples.

Comment: @Joshua I have edited my anwer. Hopt it works for you

Comment: It works! I forgot to mention that I was using strings and not files, but ```bar=$(sed -r 's/5_[0-9]+_(.*)/\1/' <<< $foo)``` worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/^5_[0-9]*_[[:alnum:]]*_\{0,1\}\(.*\)$/\1/' file
bar
name
blah
hip

can_be_any_length_and_most_but_not_all_have_underscores
```

Or using `sed -r`:

```
sed -r 's/^5_[0-9]+_[[:alnum:]]+_?(.*)$/\1/' file
bar
name
blah
hip

can_be_any_length_and_most_but_not_all_have_underscores
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the question, "I want to match everything after the last `_`", my understanding is that the question asks to take the string `5_100_foo_bar` and return the match `foo_bar`.

In this case, one could use the command

```
sed 's/5_[0-9]*_\(.*\)/\1/' example.txt
```

We first match the pattern you specify, `5_[0-9]*_`. Then, the pattern `\(.*\)` will match any number of characters and store them as `\1`.

Result:

```
foo_bar
string_name
blah_blah
hip_hip
hooray
they_can_be_any_length_and_most_but_not_all_have_underscores
```

Comment: I'm being sloppy, in my head I said it correctly. I meant everything after the second underscore (the "last" in the prefix)

Answer (score 2):

If your input is only the "word" you are trying to deal with then this will work.

```
$ cut -d_ -f3- file
foo_bar
string_name
blah_blah
hip_hip
hooray
they_can_be_any_length_and_most_but_not_all_have_underscores
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything after the second underscore:

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*_\(.*\)
```